# How to make sure you only show updated data from Rest api

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, rest

I've created and application and a paginated api which is hooked up to each other. However i'm a bit confused on what is best practice in terms of only showing updated data. For instance if i retrieve data one day and save it into my mobile database. How will the app the next day know that it should make a request and only show that particular data that just has been fetched from the database. Do i need to make somekind of flag or look at createdAt?

Comment: I'm sorry Eric D. but do you have any recommendation for this issue?

Comment: could you please tell me how frequently your data change at server side.

Comment: the data doesnt change often however it returns data based on distance of the users location, so therefor the result may vary a lot.

Comment: you mean if the user location change then the data change.

Comment: yes that is correct.

Comment: what diameter you have set for user location,means at what distance change of location user will get new results.If the diameter is big then you can compare the last location and current location,according to that call the api.

Comment: The safest way, usually, is to load fresh data everytime the user opens the app. Actually, that should be the first implementation. The question is not when you should refresh, the question is when you can use the old data. And the answer to that is 1/ parameters of the call did not change (e.g. your position) 2/ the data is not too old (1 hour, 12 hours, 24 hours - depends on your data).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When making the request, include either the [If-None-Match](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232#section-3.2) header with the local resource's [ETag](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232#section-2.3) or the [If-Modified-Since](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232#section-3.3) header with the date the local resource was requested.

Configure your server to look for the header and return a [304 Not Modified](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232#section-4.1) if the data hasn't changed. That will at least save you some traffic on the responses.

In addition, if the resource data is relatively static, or if the client can tolerate having stale client data, then you can add [caching headers](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-5) to your response. As long as the cached request is valid, the request will never leave your client.

Ideally, you want do design your API to support this where possible. For example, have the request "give me all things in 50 meters" return a list of URIs. Then the API will only have to hit the server for those URIs which are stale.

Comment: Would you limit the number of records or just set a radius like 50 meters as u mentioned in the rest api?

Comment: @PeterPik I can't really answer that. You'll have to ask somebody on the business side of your shop which one they want.

Comment: well i mean in terms of server side load time? if you only limit to meters, you  could get a lot of records

Comment: @PeterPik If that's a concern, then sure, limit the total number of records returned. It's difficult to give specific advise without specific information. :)